# Is there an elegant way to mix custom props and native props for a REACT TS component wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have several components that extends the native functionalities of elements like inputs, buttons, tables etc. and find it tedious to have to include every event handler and props as the team needs them.

I have tried to simply make the component prop type extend the native prop type and then using object spreading to apply all native props automatically. The next issue is that the custom props aren't supported and shouldn't be applied to the native element.

To solve this the only solution i have found is to duplicate the names of every custom prop in the component parameters like this: {customProp1, customProp2, ...nativeProps}. However this solution, while it is a lot better than having to add all the native props, it forces me to duplicate all the props and i loose the props. prefix that i like using for differentiating between props and local variables.

Is there a neat way to filter out the native props from the custom props?

Example of what i am trying to achieve:

```js
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
    color: string,
}

const Button = ({...props}: Props, {...nativeProps} : React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  return (
    <button {...nativeProps} style={{backgroundColor: props.color}}  />
  )
}

export default Button
```

My current best solution which involves duplicating every prop name and using spread operator on the rest.

```js
import React from 'react'

type CustomProps = {
    color: string,
    label: React.ReactNode,
    name: string,
}

type Props = CustomProps & Omit<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, keyof CustomProps>;

const Button = ({color, label, ...props}: Props) => {

  return (
    <>
        {label}
        <button {...props} style={{backgroundColor: color}} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Button
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `interface` with `extends`?

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IButtonProps
  extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    HTMLButtonElement
  > {
  color: string;
}

const Button = ({ color, ...props }: IButtonProps) => {
  return <button {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />;
};

export default Button;
```

Otherwise, you could nest your native button props:

```js
import React from "react";

interface IButtonProps {
  color: string;
  buttonProps?: React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    HTMLButtonElement
  >;
}

const Button = ({ buttonProps, ...props }: IButtonProps) => {
  return <button {...buttonProps} style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return <Button color='red' buttonProps={{ disabled: true }} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes i have but the issue is the same, the custom props are still being passed to the button element. The markup looks like this:
<button type="submit" color="red" name="hello" style="background-color: red;">Send</button>
The prop color shouldn't have been passed along, that is what i am trying to avoid by separating the props into two separate variables

Comment: Of course not because you are using spread operation: `{ color, ...props }`. `color` here is extracted from props. Can you confirm?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, i have just added an example of my previous solution which essentially is the same. But what i would like to do is avoid duplicating all the custom prop names in the parameters

Comment: I have updated my answer with an other way to do it.

Comment: Ah yes, that could be a good way to do it although it would mean a lot of refactoring to make it work with legacy code. It's a shame there aren't neat ways to filter an object by type. Thank you for your time

Comment: I'll wait a bit to see if i can get a better solution. I find it very hard to believe that it isn't possible to filter an object based on an overlapping type. I know about the Pick and Omit type filtering, but using the spread operator completely negates the casting